# How can I fix my locale configuration?

Tags: linux, debian, locale

Hello. I'm getting some warnings when running `perl`:

```
perl -e 'print "Hello\n";'
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Running:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

fixes the warnings for the current shell session

Is there any permanent solution?

Comment: which OS is this ? WakiMiko's answer is correct for debian based linux distributions. Others would need different actions. (sorry just saw the debian tag, would be better to add the distribution in the question itself)

Comment: @0xAF, Debian 6.0 64bit

Answer (score 1):

Try `dpkg-reconfigure locales`.

Comment: I'v tried it. I choose English utf-8, but after my relogin I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I was having this exact problem and on debian this can be done with the `update-locale` utility

```
update-locale --reset
```

will cause the `/etc/default/locale` file to be ignored (it simply comments out the `LANG` variable); resulting in a `locale` of:

```
LANG=C
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C

update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

will set your `LANG` to `LANG` to... you guessed it `en_US.UTF-8` resulting in `locale` generating:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

And finally just to cover all my bases...

```
update-locale LANG=C
```

will set your `LANG` to `LANG` to `C` resulting in `locale` outputting:

```
LANG=C
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=
```

I put this on unix too, which so I could try and help, cause this was driving me nuts. OCD and all.
-Eric